# How to open a new windows on body load in blogger?

Tags: wordpress, blogspot

I have my blog under url http://www.funjin.blogspot.com and i want to open a new window having specific url when the blog loads. Can anybody help?

Comment: do you want to open new window on this blogspot.com url?

Comment: @jogesh_pi Yes, exactly

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript to open a popup window when a user logs on. However, if you have a popup blocker installed, it won't open at all. Also, some browsers will not allow popups at all. It would be better to have the user click a link and then the popup opens.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
window.open('http://www.google.com','google',' menubar=0, resizable=0,dependent=0,status=0,width=300,height=200,left=10,top=10')
}
</script>
```

Change the settings for url, width, and height to whatever you need.